# Widget not overlapping on one side its going behind another widget while using `PageView()`

Tags: flutter, dart, transform

I'm creating a custom carousel using `Pageview.builder()`.
I want the active widget to come on top of the other 2 widgets which are on left and right.
So, to do that I'm using `transform` property of `AnimatedContainer`.

Problem: I've used this `Matrix4.diagonal3Values()` to make the effect but it only happened on the left side. But it doesn't happening on the right side.
How do I make that the right side also comes behind the active widget.

```
transform: active
              ? Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1.1, 1, 1)
              : Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1.2, 1, 1),
```

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Main page of the widget (Carousel)
class CarouselScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CarouselScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CarouselScreen> createState() => _CarouselScreenState();
}

class _CarouselScreenState extends State<CarouselScreen> {
  int activePage = 0;
  late PageController _pageController;
  List<String> images = [
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1191403/pexels-photo-1191403.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/9020063/pexels-photo-9020063.png?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/12437389/pexels-photo-12437389.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1',
    'https://images.pexels.com/photos/58997/pexels-photo-58997.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1'
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.7, initialPage: 0);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
          child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 350,
            child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: images.length,
                pageSnapping: true,
                controller: _pageController,
                onPageChanged: (page) {
                  setState(() => activePage = page);
                },
                itemBuilder: (context, pagePosition) {
                  bool active = pagePosition == activePage;
                  return slider(images, pagePosition, active);
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Widget slider(images, pagePosition, active) {
  double margin = active ? 10 : 20;

  return SizedBox(
    child: Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      children: [
        AnimatedContainer(
          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
          transform: active
              ? Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1.1, 1, 1)
              : Matrix4.diagonal3Values(1.2, 1, 1),
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: margin),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                images[pagePosition],
              ),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // date
        AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOutCubic,
          right: active ? 10 : -20,
          top: active ? 10 : 20,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 10,
              vertical: 10,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            child: const Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text(
                  '12',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Dec',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 12,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Currently this is what its showing

[image: here]